# bash syntax error near unexpected token `(' caused by <() trick

Tags: bash, openssl

I'm trying to execute this command :

```sh
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in cert.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAc reateserial -out tls.crt -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:${DNS}")
```

But I get the following error :

```
certificates.sh: line 44: syntax error near unexpected token `('
certificates.sh: line 44: `    openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in cert.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out tls.crt -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:orchestrator")'
```

I can't figure out where the syntaxe is wrong... Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could it be that you are not running bash, or a version which does not support process substitution yet? Comment out the offending statement and do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` in its place, and report what version you see.

Comment: Also, bash will disable some of its nonstandard features, including process substitution, if it's run under the name `sh`. What shebang does the script have, and how are you running it?

Comment: @user1934428, I'm running it on iterm2 and MacOs:
 sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)

Comment: @GordonDavisson the shebang is : #!/bin/bash
and I'm running the script with : sh my_script.sh

Comment: @LouisHulot : Then this is the problem: By running it with `sh`, you don't run it as bash script. The #! line is irrelevant here.

Comment: It did the trick thank you !